# jQuery selectable creates extra white space, \r\n, and redundant items when stored in Array

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a selectable that has a few strange behaviors. for functionality a click is used to select and de-select an item.

issue 1) sometime when I select an item it will not unselect. Actually it appears that the border of the item was deselected but I have to use some combo of cntrl+click or click drag jiggling to get it to deselect. It looks like it is actually selecting the border, the padding, and the item or something like that.

This leads to issue 2) after I have selected items I can run a script which will alert box the selected items. Sometimes my selection are repeated (exactly 1, 2, or 3 times). If for example I have trouble unselecting and only the border unselects it will list twice. Else that selected item will show up three times. Here is an example with two items selected but one item repeats twice.

```
"Community College Expert\r\n                                ,Physician Researcher and Clinician,Physician Researcher and Clinician"
```

Issue 3) there is a lot of white space in the array I am building with my clicks and a \r\n is showing up too. Here is an example with three items selected where the double/triple selection redundancy doesn't occur but there is a lot of white space with carriage row returns of some sort:

```
`"Chief Research Officer (academic)\r\n                                ,\r\n                                    Director\r\n                                ,\r\n                                    Physician Researcher and Clinician"`
```

Finally here is the code. I hacked this together from various sources. This is what I am selecting with:

```
 <script>
    var _selectRange = false, _deselectQueue = [];
    $(function() {
        $( ".selectable" ).selectable({
            selecting: function (event, ui) {
                if (event.detail == 0) {
                    _selectRange = true;
                    return true;
                }
                if ($(ui.selecting).hasClass('ui-selected')) {
                    _deselectQueue.push(ui.selecting);
                }
            },
            unselecting: function (event, ui) {
                $(ui.unselecting).addClass('ui-selected');
            },
            stop: function () {
                if (!_selectRange) {
                    $.each(_deselectQueue, function (ix, de) {
                        $(de)
                            .removeClass('ui-selecting')
                            .removeClass('ui-selected');
                    });
                }
                _selectRange = false;
                _deselectQueue = [];
            }
        });
    });       
</script>
```

and this is how I'm getting my array of items:

```
 function getSelected() {
        var selectedVals = [];
        $('#selectable2 .ui-selected').each(function(k,v) {
            selectedVals.push($(v).text());
        });
        document.getElementById("hidTag").value = selectedVals;
        alert(selectedVals);
    }
```

As you can see they are pushed to a hidden field that gets inserted into SQL table.

```
 positionTags = Request.Form["hidPostag"].Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");
```

I actually have two selectables on the page so both have the .selectable class and have IDs of #selectable2 and #selectable1. I haven't wired up selectable1 yet. here is the code for where selectable2 is coming from:

```
  @{
     var db =Database.Open("mydb");                        
     foreach (var item in db.Query("SELECT tagName FROM tag"))
      {
      var tagName = item.tagName;
       <ul class="selectable" id="selectable2">
         <li class="ui-state-default">
            <div><b>@tagName</b></div>
         </li>
        </ul>
       }                  
  <input type="hidden" name="hidTag" id="hidTag" value="" />
```

Any suggestions are welcome. --Tim

Comment: You must read [ask] and you need to create a MCVE.

Comment: Hi Amit, I will read the HTA page again and work to get my questions close to that standard. I don't know if I can create an MCVE since the selectable is populated from a SQL query. I suspect that during the foreach as items are added those \r\n bits are getting added in. (Partial solution). I just deleted the <div> inside the <li> in the foreach and that appears to have gotten rid of issue 1). Must have been creating the div and the item inside the div as selectable. I am going to look for some trim() and replace features in jquery to try to clip out the extra spaces and \r\n pieces.

Comment: I honestly couldn't follow your comment, but it appears you're on the right track to find the problem yourself through the process of creating a MCVE. That's great. That's *exactly* what should happen... You isolate and isolate till you pinpoint the exact reason for your problem and then it's so focused you can either solve it yourself or find a solution online (probably here on SO). If you're still unable to solve the issue, you'll be left with a very precise, short question that not only fits perfectly to the guidelines, it'll be much easier to answer and much more useful for future readers.